# How to dynamically add properties to class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, javabeans

I am developing framework for our products. I would like to add dynamically properties to a class. So if any of you have any sort of experience, kindly help me out.

Any of your suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Please provide some examples of what you are trying to do, just to better illustrate your problem.

Comment: Eg:
   Class Entity1
{
String name;
getter/setter;
String age;
getter/setter;
}

Suppose i want to add another field to my Entity1 class eg:designation is their any way to add it dynamically/runtime so that if my client asks me to add any other properties I can add it with less alteration of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you are asking for is not the right option here. Although in theory you can modify the byte code of your program to add a property dynamically as you describe, it is not a good idea at all.

I suggest you use a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) that maps a property name to its value and interactively modify that map.

Comment: Eg:
   Class Entity1
{
String name;
getter/setter;
String age;
getter/setter;
}

Suppose i want to add another field to my Entity1 class eg:designation is their any way to add it dynamically/runtime

Comment: can this be made using hibernate/spring .

Comment: could u please explain me how to use HashMap and interactively modify the map.Do u have any snippet code, which helps me to understand better.