# How to dynamically add class fields at runtime in Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to dynamically add properties to class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442998/how-to-dynamically-add-properties-to-class)

I would like to know is their any way to add fields to my entity class in Java, dynamically, or is their any alternative way of doing this? We are developing a framework and our existing products has this as a requirement.

Example:

```
class Entity1 {
    String name;
    String age;

    // Getters/setters;
}
```

Suppose I want to add another field to my `Entity1` class (eg: `designation`), is their any way to add it dynamically/at runtime, so that if my client asks me to add any other properties I can do it with less alteration of code?

Waiting for your reply. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Maybe you should have edited your original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442998/how-to-dynamically-add-properties-to-class

Comment: Did you check any byte code manipulation libraries.(ASM/Javassist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use javaassist to do this - hibernate use this for a lot of its cool features.

[This](http://www.javassist.org/tutorial/tutorial2.html#add) should help you get started.

You could even use groovy to achieve this so this depends on your preference and any specifics that you may have omitted from the question.

Comment: Yeap, bytecode generation/manipulation is the way to go

Comment: Link is down. Can you update please?

Comment: @Wingie done, javassist or another similar library which aids in bytecode modification will provide this functionality.